# Escaping square brackets in dictionary keys passed via query string

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, escaping, query-string

I have an API action that accepts a dictionary from the query string like so:

```
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase {
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(CancellationToken ct, [FromQuery(Name = "responses")] Dictionary<string, bool> responses, [FromBody] MyModelType model) { }
}
```

The dictionary keys describe nested properties on `model` (which is sent as the request body), e.g.:

```
Foo
Foo.Bar
Bar[2].Foo
```

For the first two keys above, the dictionary binding works fine (as you would expect):

```
POST https://localhost/MyController?responses[Foo]=true&responses[Foo.Bar]=false
```

However, for the third key it fails due to the square brackets:

```
POST https://localhost/MyController?responses[Bar[2].Foo]=false
```

...with `responses` containing a single entry with the key `Bar[2`. Clearly the input needs to be escaped, but I haven't been able to find any documentation for how to do this, and the following approaches have not worked:

```
Bar\[2\].Foo
Bar[%5B2%5D].Foo
```

How should I go about escaping square brackets in the query string when binding to a dictionary?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dictionaries You could try some form of `.Key=...`? I'm pretty sure that dictionary binding is the same as binding an `IEnumerable<KeyPair<,>>` then constructing the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following request:

```
https://localhost/MyController?responses[0].key=bar[2].Foo&responses[0].value=false
```

Result:

[image]

For you use `[FromQuery(Name = "responses")]`, so you must use `responses[index].xxx`.

Comment: Fantastic, can confirm this works in my code as well. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two ways to solve this problem. First, you can bind a dictionary by treating it exactly the same as a `List<KeyPair<,>>`. Providing;

```
https://localhost/MyController?responses[0].key=Foo&responses[0].value=true&responses[1].key=bar[2].Foo&responses[1].value=false
```

Or, rather than numeric indices, you can provide all the index names explicitly;

```
https://localhost/MyController?responses.index=Foo&responses.index=bar[2].Foo&responses[Foo]=true&responses[bar[2].Foo]=false
```